# In C if double pointer is assigned to value, why is the pointer variable 0?

Tags: c

```
int main() 
{
    int var = 10;
    int **ptr;

    **ptr = var;

    printf("%x\n",ptr);
    printf("%d\n",**ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

The above code prints: 0 and 10

Why is ptr 0 ?

How is the code showing **ptr = 10, if ptr is 0 ?

I tried printing *ptr.

This gave segmentation fault (since ptr is 0).

So, again why not throw segmentation fault at **ptr ?

Could this be related to compiler ?

PS: I am using https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler to run this code.

Comment: You have a pointer that you dereference, but ***where does it point?***

Comment: I believe this would count as undefined behaviour as the pointer was never initialized.

Comment: Also note that the format specifier to print a `void *` pointer (yes the cast is really needed) is `"%p"`.

Comment: You should choose an environment where you can get compiler warnings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You assign the pointer to pointer itself, not the the object referenced.

```
int v = 10;

int *ptr = &v;
int **ptrptr = &ptr;

printf("%d\n", **ptrptr);
```

> So, again why not throw segmentation fault at **ptr ?

By incident. This is UB and your pointer has a random value. This value points to another location with the random value. Then you dereference that second one. So if those random values point to the place in the memory allocated to your program it will not segfault. If not it will segfault.

Why it is printing `0` and `10`? Because in this case compiler has **optimized all the pointer operations out** and assumed that not initialized pointers are NULL, just printing the constant values:

```
main:
        push    {r4, lr}
        mov     r1, #0
        ldr     r0, .L3
        bl      printf
        mov     r1, #10
        ldr     r0, .L3+4
        bl      printf
        mov     r0, #0
        pop     {r4, pc}
.L3:
        .word   .LC0
        .word   .LC1
.LC0:
        .ascii  "%x\012\000"
.LC1:
        .ascii  "%d\012\000"
```

Comment: From the disassembly it seems compiler has optimized it quite a lot.
Both prints are optimized.
First one to print 0, since ptr was not initialized (mov     r1, #0)
Second one to directly print 10. Without any deference (mov     r1, #10).
Also **ptr = var; was completely dropped.

Answer (score 3):

Pointer `ptr` is not initialized. Your code invokes undefined behaviour because you are dereferencing an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: this example is too trivial and that is the reason. Compiler will not dereference anything

Comment: @P__J__; I didn't get you. *Compiler will not dereference anything* ??

Comment: Se my answer. The OPs example is too trivial and compilers will optimize the pointers out assuming the value of the uninitialized  pointers as NULL. See my answer and the compilation result. There are no memory reads (ie dereferencing) in the code - only passing the constant values to the printf